# How to set proxy for local environment in EventHubTrigger connection string for Azure Function

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I can set proxy through EventHubConnectionOptions when using EventProcessorClient and I am able to receive events. But how can I achieve the same in EventHubTrigger Azure function? In my local enviornment I cannot access azure resources without proxy.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Azure function use `proxies.json` to set proxy.

Please have a look of the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies

**Original Answer:**

> In my local [environment] I cannot access azure resources without proxy.

Below code doesn't need proxy:

**`EventHub` Trigger:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp63
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("test", Connection = "str")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {
                    string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

                    // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                    log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }

            // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

            if (exceptions.Count > 1)
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

            if (exceptions.Count == 1)
                throw exceptions.Single();
        }
    }
}
```

**Send message to event hub:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer;

namespace ConsoleApp27
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://testbowman.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=QhZeIb7KaCiNLP171jW3chJtIQDQgx0OBAOQNx7wE9g=";

            const string eventHubName = "test";
            // Create a producer client that you can use to send events to an event hub
            await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName))
            {
                // Create a batch of events 
                using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

                // Add events to the batch. An event is a represented by a collection of bytes and metadata. 
                eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("First event")));
                eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Second event")));
                eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Third event")));

                // Use the producer client to send the batch of events to the event hub
                await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
                Console.WriteLine("A batch of 3 events has been published.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One note on the above `Send message` snippet.   The pattern demonstrated has the potential for data loss.  Because the return of `TryAdd` is not checked, should any event be too large to fit into the batch, it would silently be dropped.  While this isn't likely to happen using the sample events, a production application would need to account for it.   I'd suggest referencing the [official samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample04_PublishingEvents.md#publishing-size-constraints) for best practices.

Comment: In our corporate network you cannot connect to azure without proxy, even for producer app you will need to provide proxy to send messages. that's why I used  EventHubConnectionOptions to configure proxy, but in Azure functions I don't see an option to set proxy.

Comment: @dan I have update the answer, please have a look. Let me know whether it can helps.